# Resources on OWL and Building Ontologies

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology

Why is **video material** so spare or of low quality on OWL and Ontologies in general? I want to learn how to use OWL by example (like we do AngularJS, ASP.NET MVC ...etc) through video tutorials, but there is nothing out there!

Anyone know of good walk throughs where someone takes a fairly simple domain, models it in OWL and consumes content based on the built ontology?

It is so hard to grasp these concepts and a solid walk through would help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some nice Protege tutorials which you can use to learn OWL and building ontologies. Here is one example which does exactly what you ask for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbauHV2-XYw

Alternatively, one of the most famous examples for learning OWL concepts is the Pizza tutorial. I haven't found a video, but this document summarizes everything in an incremental way. I really recommend it: http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf